# Aggregating query giving unwanted results

Tags: mysql, join, aggregate

I have wrote a query to pull out all outstanding backorders only displaying lines that can be fulfilled (checking stock levels against order qty).

I want to summarise each of these orders into one row.

Customer Name / Order id / Sum(Qty outstanding)/ sum(qtyToSend) / sum(unitSell)

Currently my output looks like this - if anyone can offer any guidance or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

[image: Output]

```
SELECT 
    c.cus_name,
    ol.orderLines_orderId,
    oh.orderHeader_status,
    ol.orderLines_stockRef,
    ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered,
    ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced, 
    ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered - ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced as qtyOutstanding,
    (CASE
        WHEN ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered - ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced > pr.products_instock THEN pr.products_instock
        ELSE (ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered - ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced)
    END) AS qtyToSend,
    pr.products_instock,
    FORMAT(ol.orderLines_totalSell/ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered,2) as unitSell
FROM
    cus c
        JOIN
    orderheader oh ON oh.orderHeader_customer = c.cus_id
        JOIN
    orderlines ol ON ol.orderLines_orderId = oh.orderHeader_id
        JOIN
    products pr ON ol.orderlines_stockref = pr.products_reference
WHERE
    ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered <> ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced
HAVING
    qtytosend > 0
```

I have tried to do it this way but the value of the order is not correct. The total value of the backorders should be £34.42 by my calculation for Row 1 (Emiliano's Gifts Bros)

[image]

```
SELECT 
    c.cus_name,
    ol.orderLines_orderId,
    sum(ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered - ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced )as qtyOutstanding,
    sum((CASE
        WHEN ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered - ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced > pr.products_instock THEN pr.products_instock
        ELSE (ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered - ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced)
    END))AS qtyToSend,
    sum(FORMAT(ol.orderLines_totalSell/ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered,2)) as unitSell
FROM
    cus c
        JOIN
    orderheader oh ON oh.orderHeader_customer = c.cus_id
        JOIN
    orderlines ol ON ol.orderLines_orderId = oh.orderHeader_id
        JOIN
    products pr ON ol.orderlines_stockref = pr.products_reference
WHERE
    ol.orderLines_qtyOrdered <> ol.orderlines_qtyInvoiced
GROUP BY
    ol.orderLines_orderId
HAVING
    qtytosend > 0
```

Comment: Without sample data we will be guessing, but when a query involves several joins, a very common solution to aggregation errors is to perform the aggregations **before** joining (i.e. join a subquery, not the source table).

Comment: `sum(FORMAT( x / y ,2))` "format" returns a string, if you really only want to sum the rounded numbers, then use `sum(ROUND( x / y ,2))` instead. Or only apply the format after the sum `FORMAT(sum( x / y) ,2)`